# ifelse using some conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

my data set is similar to this and I want to use ifelse or other functions in R. I can do it easily in Excel, but not sure how to do it it in R.

```
df<-read.table(text=" Items Goods

Mug1    Cup1
Mug1    Mug2
Mug1    NA
Mug2    Mug1
Mug2    Cup2
Cup1    Mug1
Cup2    Mug2
Mug2    Cup1
Cup1    Mug2", header=TRUE)
```

Conditions are:

```
Mug1=Cup1
Mug2=Cup2
Cup1=Mug1
Cup2=Mug2
```

If I see  the above condition, They are  considered as correct. otherwise they are incorrect. I have searched, but I could not find any solution, but it is likely I have missed some websites. Any help

I will get this table then

```
Items   Goods   Out
Mug1    Cup1    Correct
Mug1    Mug2    Incorrect
Mug1    NA  NA
Mug2    Mug1    Incorrect
Mug2    Cup2    Correct
Cup1    Mug1    Correct
Cup2    Mug2    Correct
Mug2    Cup1    Incorrect
Cup1    Mug2    Incorrect
```

Comment: Hi user2343213 and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you tell us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck? Are you just looking for a tutorial on R basics?

Comment: I am not looking for a tutorial... I was looking to find out a an easy solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use a named vector, replace the values in 'Goods' by using the named vector, do a comparison (`==`) with 'Items' to return a logical vector, which can be either used in `ifelse` or convert to a position index and replace values based on that index to 'Correct', 'Incorrect'

```
nm1 <- setNames(c("Mug1", "Mug2"), c("Cup1", "Cup2"))
nm2 <- c(nm1, setNames(names(nm1), nm1))
df$Out <-  with(df, c("Incorrect", "Correct")[1 + (as.character(Items) == 
    nm2[as.character(Goods)])])
df
#  Items Goods       Out
#1  Mug1  Cup1   Correct
#2  Mug1  Mug2 Incorrect
#3  Mug1  <NA>      <NA>
#4  Mug2  Mug1 Incorrect
#5  Mug2  Cup2   Correct
#6  Cup1  Mug1   Correct
#7  Cup2  Mug2   Correct
#8  Mug2  Cup1 Incorrect
#9  Cup1  Mug2 Incorrect
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
with(df, unname(ifelse(as.character(Items) == 
    nm2[as.character(Goods)], "Correct", "Incorrect")))
#[1] "Correct"   "Incorrect" NA          "Incorrect" "Correct"   
#[6] "Correct"   "Correct"   "Incorrect" "Incorrect"
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
library(dplyr)
df<- df%>% mutate(out = ifelse(gsub("Mug","Cup",Items)==gsub("Mug","Cup",Goods),"correct","incorrect"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I think items and goods should read Items and Goods and a bracket at the end is required?

Comment: Yes! my bad about the names and the brackets, Edited